# Is it possible to create dynamic route based on role level in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, dynamic, routes

I want to create a dynamic route in `web.php` file. I don't know if it is a bad idea or not, and also I don't know if it is possible.

So my tables are `role`, `menu`, `role_menu`

```
role : id, role_name
menu : id, title, route
role_menu : role_id, menu_id
```

I have tried like this:
[Laravel : Setting dynamic routes based on access control list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48758552/laravel-setting-dynamic-routes-based-on-access-control-list)

okay, i will explain, but it's complicated...

so, i have a feature `add role`, but just role admin can access it.
here's my `add role` feature:
[image]
let's say i will input `student` and cheklist `[client, banner, galery]`.
and when i login as student now, and i hit `mayApp/tool` (which is not allowed for student) it can access it, that's the problem.

here's my `web.php` :

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'operator'], function() {
    Route::resource('/list_of_menu', 'ListOfMenuController');
});
```

so the thing is, in the operatorMiddleware i want allowed the route only the access menu that have been checked. but i no have idea how to do it in operatorMIddleware.

if this still confusing, tell me...

Comment: Please show your code. We cannot know what is going wrong without seeing what you created.

Comment: Please show your `route` code, pls.

Comment: No it is a bad practice to send your role_id or menu_id through the routes. You can make use of gates and policies.

Comment: You better show us your `web.php` routes file, but I guess [this might help you](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters) if I am understanding your question right.

Comment: sorry guys, i have edited my question...